# Why does InstallShield ask for a restart?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have an installshield installer that works fine under normal circumstances. But when I run it while a particular software is running, the installer asks for a restart at the end.

Now on some research I have come to learn that a restart is asked only when the installer wants to modify files that are currently locked by other processes.

Is there anyway that I can find out which is the file installsheild wants to modify? (but cannot because it is locked by another process)

I would also like to know if it is only file modifications that affect the restart/no restart or is it also associated with registry key modifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [WhyReboot](http://exodusdev.com/products/WhyReboot/) after the setup, it will show you pending reboot file and registry keys that could not be modified during the setup.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem. I also found PendMoves at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx that does the same thing.

Comment: Updated link to SysInternals PendMoves: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pendmoves

Answer (score 5):

You tagged your question with "windows-installer", so I'm assuming you're using InstallShield to author an MSI installer.

Run the other software app, do a complete log of your install, like:

```
msiexec -i file.msi -l*vx test.log
```

In the resulting log, look for all lines containing "RESTART MANAGER".  You will get more data on what is prompting for the reboot.

Comment: Thank you. I have got what I want. Thanks again.

Comment: This is good info. Very often I feel that the Windows Installer log is the best method to debug Basic MSI installers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my installshield project had a "RebootPrompt" User Interface at the end of the Installation sequence with a condition "NOT INSTALLED". So all new installations would always show that Reboot prompt even if not needed.